# contar las veces de ocurrencia

Tags: r, script, rstudio

me gustaria contar con su ayuda con un script en el no tengo idea de como desarrollar en R.

en el que deseo contar cuantos veces ocurren consecutivamente algun evento

df<- c(1,2,4,**0,0,0**,4,3,0,**4,4**,**0,0,0,0,0,0**,**1,1**,2)

en donde quiero obtener las veces que aparece el cero solo consecutivamente

una idea seria:

los ceros aparecen 2 veces consecutivamente siendo 6 veces el maximo que se repiten.

los uno aparece 1 vez consecutivamente siendo 2 veces el maximo que se repiten.

los cuatro aparecen 1 vez consecutivamente siento 2 veces el maximo que se repiten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la función `rle`. Dado por como lo defines en la pregunta, voy a suponer que tu objeto (`df`) es un **vector**. La función `rle` devuelve los valores y cuantas veces se repiten consecutivamente.

No se como esperas que sea lo que obtienes finalmente, hice un `data.frame` porque es un objeto usual, en donde: la primer columna están los valores, que se repiten consecutivamente más de una vez, del objeto `df`. En la segunda están las veces que se repiten, y la tercera el número máximo de veces que se repiten consecutivamente.

```
MisVecesRep <- with(rle(df), {
  #Lo transformamos en data.frame
  Midf <- data.frame(values,lengths)
  #Sacamos los valores que se repiten una sola vez
  Midf <-Midf[Midf$lengths>1 ,] 
  #Calculamos cuantas veces se repiten en total
  VecesRep<-margin.table( table(Midf),1)
  #Calculamos cual es el maximo de veces consecutivas que se repiten
  VecesCons<-tapply(Midf$lengths,Midf$values,max)

  data.frame(VecesRep,
             "RepMax" = VecesCons)
  })
```

```
MisVecesRep 
  values Freq RepMax
0      0    2      6
1      1    1      2
4      4    1      2
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias me ayudo mucho su explicación